400 Error in Browser but Not in Postman or Terminal with Large Cookies, "400 Bad Request: Request Header or Cookie Too Large"
I have a Rails application where I encounter an issue when using large cookies. For example, at https://api.my-app.com/v1 (an API endpoint) and https://app.my-app.com (the main app)in a browser, it initially loads fine. However, as I manually add cookies, the application stops working once the total cookie size exceeds 8KB, showing a 400 Bad Request. Here’s what happens:
If I visit the URL in a browser (in incognito mode), it loads correctly.
I then start adding cookies manually until the total size reaches 8KB. The application still works fine up to this point.
Once the total cookie size exceeds 8KB, I get a
400 Bad Request, Request Header Or Cookie Too Large, nginx
error.
There are no other cookies in the browser aside from the ones I’m adding, and I verified via DevTools that only my custom cookies are sent in the request.
However, if I copy the failing request as a cURL command from the network tab and run it in my terminal or send it through Postman (even with a cookie size up to 10-12KB), it works perfectly without any errors.
In my Kubernetes ingress configuration, I have set the following annotations to handle larger header sizes:
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
  client_header_buffer_size 16k;
  large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;

Here’s the cURL command that replicates the request. I use three cookies in the request:

large_cookie1 with 4,000 a characters
large_cookie2 with 4,000 b characters
large_cookie3 with 200 c characters

From both the terminal and Postman, I receive a response without errors. However, in the browser, this request returns a 400 error. If I remove large_cookie3, the browser also receives a fine response.
curl 'https://api.my-app.com/v1' \
  -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'cookie: large_cookie1=aaa...; large_cookie2=bbb...; large_cookie3=ccc..' \
  -H 'pragma: no-cache' \
  -H 'priority: u=0, i' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Not A(Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="132", "Google Chrome";v="132"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: document' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: navigate' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: none' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-user: ?1' \
  -H 'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/132.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'


It seems that this issue only affects requests made from a browser, and I’m not sure why it would behave differently in a terminal or Postman.
What could be causing this discrepancy, and how can I resolve it so that large cookies are accepted in browser requests as well?

"I have a Rails application where I encounter an issue when using large cookies." - Using large cookies is bad practice for a number of reasons -- one of which is performance, another is that some browsers limit the total size of cookies per request. "Doctor it hurts when I do that." -- "Don't do that."

Check this.

The HTTP 400 Bad Request client error response status code indicates that the server would not process the request due to something the server considered to be a client error.
Any cookie that is set with a size greater than the limit is ignored (and not set).
Most of the browsers have a limit on the size of cookies, check Browser cookie limits for some common browsers. When the total size of cookies exceeds this limit, browsers may reject the request. For example Chrome browser has 180 Cookie count limit per domain Total size of cookies 4096.
The error message Request Header Or Cookie Too Large. One of your headers is very big, and nginx is rejecting it. You are using nginx server, try to increase the buffer value and set it as large_client_header_buffers 4 32k.
Check your Kubernetes ingress annotations to ensure they are correctly applied and that the ingress controller is properly configured to handle large headers.
Refer to this document by Docdevs for more information
Note:

To support most browsers, cookies should not exceed 60 per domain, and total cookie size (across all cookies) should be less than or equal to 4093 bytes.

